# primefaces print screen with some text at the page footer

Tags: html, css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have the primefaces xhtml page. It has print button to print the current form.
How to print some text at the page footer??

```
<p:commandButton value="Print" onclick="finishPrint()">
    <p:printer target="panel1s6" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try CSS2 @media rules to distinguish `screen` and `print` stylings:

```
@media screen {
    .print_footer {display: none;}
}
@media print {
    .print_footer {display: block;}
}
```

Then, if you have some html code within your form like:

```
<div class="print_footer">Some footer</div>
```

it will be not shown on the screen, but will be printed instead. This is general idea, you have to style appropriate layout for the `print` media.